# Average request duration using Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio, duration, latency

I have deployed the Istio Bookinfo application in a Kubernetes cluster. Following the documentation, I'm trying to measure the average request duration using the following query:

```
rate(istio_request_duration_milliseconds_sum[1m]) / rate(istio_request_duration_milliseconds_count[1m])
```

This query returns me "doubled" results i.e. for each request I get two results, with different *Value* but same *source* and *destination*, one labelled as *reporter="source"* and the other as *reporter="destination"*. I was not able to find any clarification about it and I have not clear how these measures work. Why I have two values returned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The metrics are indeed reported from two sources, once from the request sender and another time from the request receiver. This is a bit redundant, but in some situations the values differ and especially for requests duration: from request sender (`reporter=source`), the duration stands for the whole request latency (server processing time + network roundtrip) whereas from the request receiver (`reporter=destination`), it stands mainly for server processing time.

In a few special situations there is no redundancy and metrics are only reported once (be it from source or from destination): e.g. when istio features such as fault injection or traffic mirroring come into play.

As a result, in Prometheus you should always filter all your queries with either `{reporter="source"}` or `{reporter="destination"}`.